# (auto-generated?) _ids gives ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Suppose I have models

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :widget_spots
```

and

```
class WidgetSpot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :widget
```

Also, in my MySQL table 'widget_spots', I have a column 'widget_id'

```
+--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                 | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| widget_id          | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
                ................
+--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now, if in my rails console, trying to access the widget_spot_ids gives an error.

```
> widget = widgets.find(:first)
> widget.widget_spot_ids
ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey: ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:374:in `primary_key'
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:228:in `association_primary_key'
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:51:in `ids_reader'
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/builder/collection_association.rb:62:in `block in define_readers'
    from (irb):12
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails-3.1.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

However, getting the instances gives a list without an error:`> widget.widget_spots` performs the expected SQL query and gives a list.

How can I figure out where and how is the `ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey` error being generated. Which primary key is it trying to find in which database?

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because the target `widget_spots` table has it's primary key composed of multiple fields.